# Troubles with grunt.js when calling it from bash script

Tags: bash, node.js, gruntjs

When i call grunt (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt), from same directory with grunt.js it is working ok.

But, if i try to make such bash script called "build.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
`grunt grunt.js`
```

and when i call ./build.sh it gives following error:

> ./build.sh: line 2: Running: command not found

I tried to specify full path to grunt, also tried to specify full path to grunt.js file with config, but it don't want to work :(

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the ` marks, because that means "substitute the output of the command". All you want is

```
#!/bin/bash
grunt grunt.js
```

Alternatively, `exec grunt grunt.js`.